# Handle errors in lambdas triggered by SQS with batchSize > 1

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've setup an AWS SQS queue that triggers a lambda function. As the default behavior, the lambda can be triggered with up to 10 messages at once (default batchSize).

If the lambda fails for any reason, it will fail the entire batch and eventually retry. But let's say I have an email sending lambda, it executes for the N first cases successfully, but fails in N+1. If it retries the whole batch, it will duplicate emails.

Currently I can only think of making the batchSize 1 to avoid this problem, but I was hoping to avoid it. Is there another way to do it?

The node code is very simple, something like this:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    await Promise.all(
      event.Records.map(async record => {
        // SEND EMAIL ASYNC
      });
    );
  } catch (error) {
    [...];
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to work around this is to keep track of which messages succeed and which failed (done within your map function) and in the catch section re-add messages that failed (can be located with `ReceiptHandle`) to the queue. Then instead of throwing the error, return successfully which will cause the entire batch to be cleared from the queue.

I believe the converse of deleting successful messages with `deleteMessageBatch` and the `ReceiptHandle` and throwing an error so that the rest of the batch is not automatically cleared could work but I haven't tried deleting in-flight messages.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

When Lambda reads a message from the queue, it stays in the queue but becomes hidden until Lambda deletes it. If your function returns an error, or doesn't finish processing before the queue's visibility timeout, it becomes visible again.

Comment: This solution can cause infinite loop. Look at this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234199/splittling-sqs-lambda-batch-into-partial-success-partial-failure

Comment: Thanks for bringing up that issue and for linking a post that resolves it!